# Prevent developer from placing a UserControl more than one time in Design Time

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls, visual-studio-2017

I am working on a `UserControl` and I am looking for a way to **prevent** developer to **place** this `UserControl` more than one time into a form. All this in **Design Time**. In other words, how can I **detect** if my `UserControl` is already **placed** into `ParentForm` or not, in **Design Time**(!!!), and **prevent** the **second placement** if there is already one there?

I tried something like this example below... First I am not sure if this is the "correct" way and second I can't find how to remove or stop the placement of `UserControl` in case there is already one.

Again, all this, in **Design Time**!!!

```
Private Sub MyUserControl_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 
    Dim _Count As Integer
    Dim _UserControl As MyUserControl
    For Each _UserControl In Me.ParentForm.Controls
        If _UserControl.Name.Contains("MyUserControl") Then
            _Count += 1
        End If
    Next
    If _Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox("Control have been placed.")
    Else
        MsgBox("Control haven't placed yet.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Add tag with technology you use (winforms?)

Comment: The Q&D way is to throw an exception in your Load event handler.  The message box does not win any prizes, but you'll certainly stop the second control from being added.  The non-Q way is to create your own designer.

Comment: @IvanH: Yes winforms!

Comment: @HansPassant: About your non-q way... How can I do that using an "own designer"?

Comment: Hmya, that is the question I did not want to answer, the designer class you want to derive from is internal.  Use a good decompiler and look at the UserControlDocumentDesigner class in System.Design.dll.  Copy/paste its code.  It is already close to what you want, its CanDropComponents() method now prevents a MainMenu from being dropped.

Comment: @HansPassant: I got it. Thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: You have access to everything you need when the `Site` Property is set.  I have shown this technique to you [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49657344/2592875).  You can iterate over the `host.Container.Components` collection to determine if a prior instance exists.  If a prior instance exists, use ` host.DestroyComponent(Me)` to remove the new instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly I ended to this...

```
Private Sub Me_ParentChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.ParentChanged

    Dim _ParentForm = DirectCast(Me.FindForm, Control)
    Dim _ControlName As String

    If _ParentForm IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each _Control As Control In _ParentForm.Controls
            If TypeOf _Control Is MyUserControl AndAlso _Control IsNot Me Then
                Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("", "You can place only one " & _ControlName & " control per form.")
            End If
            _Control = _ParentForm.GetNextControl(_Control, True)
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

for this same form is easy use new and dispose, it not work in beat weans forms. only in this same. U can use mutex or some singleton instant of this module property or other inform method that this was created and when was disposed.

```
    Sub New()
    '  This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    If Not co Is Nothing Then Throw New Exception
    co = Me ' assign public propert in  module or singleton

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub
```

> ```
> Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
>     Try
>         If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
>             components.Dispose()
>         End If
>     Finally
>         co = Nothing
>         MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
>     End Try
> End Sub
> ```

```
Module common
Property co As UserControl1
```

End Module